# meaning of the phrase "as far as" + a verb in its progressive form?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here it goes:

> Today I am going to show you exactly how a lot of people will improve their hip flexion **as far as** **going** into a physical therapy clinic.

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/JJjl2xULPpw). It is at around 1 miute and 3 second. I have checked all the meanings of the phrase *as far as*, but I still have no idea what the coach was trying to say by that.

Comment: There's no saying for certain what that sentence means.  I can only guess that it means "to a degree that one would  achieve by going into a PT clinic (and doing the PT exercises)".

Comment: "Today, she is going to show great patience as far as answering questions."

Comment: @Lambie: I don't think that example sheds much light on the original sentence.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo It's the same idea, the same structure, the same exact thing.

Comment: I agree with Tᴚoɯɐuo. No matter how hard I tried to get the meaning of the sentence, I cannot see how "as far as" can fit there.

Comment: @Lambie: In your answering questions sentence, what does **as far as** mean?  "with respect to"? That is, she will be patient in the way she answers?  Or that  she will be so patient that she will even answer questions?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I believe you have described the most likely intended meaning in your first comment.  The grammatical phenomenon of interest here is **elision** - the omission of a phrase which would be repeated.  The **non-elided** version of the same sentence (with the same meaning) would be, "Today I am going to show you exactly how a lot of people will *improve their hip flexion* **as far as going** into a physical therapy clinic *will improve their hip flexion*."  As you said, the meaning of 'as far as' in this context is "to the same degree that."

Comment: A clearer version of OP's sentence would be, "Today I'll show you a way that a lot of people can achieve the same improvement in their hip flexion as they could by going into a physical therapy clinic, but without having to go to the clinic."  @Lambie is correct that "going into a physical therapy clinic" is a gerund phrase and *not* actually a progressive form.

Answer (score 0):

"going into a physical therapy clinic" is not a progressive tense.

It is a noun phrase, using a gerund:

**Playing tennis** is fun. **Going to a physical therapy clinic is not**.

Also,  As far as= in terms of, with regard to.

Please  note: "going to a clinic" is not exactly the same as "going into a clinic". We commonly use "going to x" to mean: seek treatment at a place.

"Going to a clinic" means using a clinic as the  place to treat an injury. "Going into a clinic" means entering a clinic, physically, or staying at a clinic (like a hospital) for treatment. Generally, though, one doesn't stay overnight at a clinic.

"As far as" means **as regards, with respect to, in terms of** and can be used with regular nouns or gerunds nouns:

As far as going to a clinic=as regards going to a clinic, with respect to going to a clinic

Often, "as far as" is used with "concerned": as far as going to a clinic [is concerned]. In terms of going to a clinic.

Comment: I am aware what "as far as" means, still it is not clear to me what the speaker means

Comment: "going to a clinic" is a noun phrase, just like these: answering questions, playing tennis, doing math, having fun, getting sandwiches. Those are not verbs in a progressive form. Do you understand those noun phrases? Answering questions is hard work. In American English, we use as far as to mean: with regard to something. **As far as answering questions**, I might not answer anymore of them today.

Comment: [useful advice: you might want to correct the spelling of the word gym (not jym) in your profile and capitalize the word English.]

Comment: I cannot get how people can improve their hip flexion as far as/in regard to going to a clinic. What I would understand if the speaker said "people can improve their hip flexion when they go to a clinic". I cannot see how the phrase "as far as" fit in there.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hopen Yes, it means that exactly. You can improve x by going to y.   But bear in mind the guy is talking, and not everything comes in neat, little packages when people speak. Spontaneous speech is messy.